# JMeter script override session cookies for multiple login API

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

I am planning to conduct a load test on an application using JMeter. In this test, I intend to simulate the concurrent login of 100 users, using 2 Active Directory user accounts. This translates to 50 concurrent users per Active Directory account.

The login API returns a session cookie in the header, and subsequent API requests are valid only if a valid session cookie is present in the header. The API flow is structured as follows:

Login API
Get List API
Get Detail API
To implement this scenario, I have created two threads in my load test. Each thread represents one Active Directory account. **However, I have encountered an issue where the second thread (Thread #2) succeeds in making API calls, while the first thread (Thread #1) fails with an "invalid session cookie" response. It appears that the last thread (Thread #2) is overwriting the session cookie in the header.**

Here's the structure of how I have set up the threads:

```
Thread Group
->HTTP Cookie Manager
->User Defined Variables
->Login API
->GetList API 
->GetDetail API
Thread Group
->HTTP Cookie Manager
->User Defined Variables
->Login API
->GetList API 
->GetDetail API
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that each thread maintains its own session cookie. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I would expect these Thread call API with separate session cookie in the header and response success

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your script has 2 instances of User Defined Variables, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

so if you're defining a variable like username in there - the one which goes later will overwrite the value which is set by the one which is earlier so you're basically using one username instead of 2.

1. You can remove 2nd Thread Group and just set 2 threads in 1st Thread Group:

   [image]
2. Whenever you will need to re-use a Sampler or a piece of script in another place consider moving it into a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference it using a [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) instead, this is JMeter's way of following [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle